# How to write retryable-exception-classes using Spring Batch Annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

We're migrating from `Spring Batch XML` based application to latest `Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE` version application at this moment.

I've the below XML Snippet which I want to convert it into the Annotation based Job. I am really struggling to find these options, as I went through https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#taskletStep.

```
<batch:job id="myJob">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" commit-interval="100" retry-limit="3" skip-limit="3">
                <batch:retryable-exception-classes>
                    <batch:exclude class="org.springframework.dao.PessimisticLockingFailureException"/>
                </batch:retryable-exception-classes>
                <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                    <batch:include class="org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException"/>
                </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Another snippet:

```
<bean id="retryPolicy" class="org.springframework.retry.policy.ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy">
    <property name="policyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="org.springframework.dao.ConcurrencyFailureException">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.retry.policy.SimplreRetryPolicy">
                    <property name="maxAttempts" value="3" />
                </bean>
            </entry>
            <entry key="org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.retry.policy.SimplreRetryPolicy">
                    <property name="maxAttempts" value="5" />
                </bean>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a toggle at the top of each page that lets you choose which configuration style (XML or Java) you want to see in the code examples:

[image]

Now for the [retryable exceptions section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/step.html#retryLogic), here is the code with XML config:

[image]

And the equivalent in Java config:

[image]

If you want to provide a custom retry policy, you can use [FaultTolerantStepBuilder#retryPolicy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/builder/FaultTolerantStepBuilder.html#retryPolicy-org.springframework.retry.RetryPolicy-).

Comment: Oh, got it thanks, but I don't see a way to see `<batch:retryable-exception-classes>`  and `<batch:skippable-exception-classes>` add `<batch:include>` and `<batch:exclude>`

Comment: use `FaultTolerantStepBuilder#retry` / `FaultTolerantStepBuilder#noRetry` to include/exclude retryable exceptions and `FaultTolerantStepBuilder#skip`/`FaultTolerantStepBuilder#noSkip` to include/exclude skippable exceptions.